# How to delete row with the lowest id using Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm wondering what is the idomatic Django equivalent of:

```
DELETE FROM article WHERE ID = ( SELECT Min( ID ) FROM article )
```

What I have tried is to retrieve the article with the lowest id

```
article = Article.objects.all().order_by("-id")[:1]
```

And then:

```
Article.objects.filter(id=article.id).delete()
```

But I'm wondering if there is more efficient/elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a single query, since Django manages some relations itself. If you perform a delete, it will first obtain the items you plan to delete, then check if some triggers need to be peformed, and then delete the related objects that need to be removed and the object(s) itself.

You can thus do something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(
    pk=Model.objects.annotate(min=Min('pk')
).values('min')[:1]).delete()
```

But it will still result in multiple queries.

Probably the most elegant way to do this is:

```
article = Article.objects.order_by('id').first()
if article:
    article.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to django documentation:

> [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) 
>   Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object. If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

You can use this command:

```
Article.objects.all().first().delete() if Article.objects.all().first() else None
```

Comment: You probably should guard against `None`?

Comment: According to the docs, this line should be in a try/except to deal with `None`.